# Xcode Autolayout And Screen Orientation

Tags: ios, xcode, autolayout

What is the correct constraint for two views arranged vertically when portrait, and when phone becomes landscape the two views will automatically arrange horizontally.

[image]
[image]

Comment: you cannot rearrange the layout with using _auto-layout_ at the moment, there is no sequence of constraints which would do this job for you automatically.

Comment: If that is the case I will be using @paul.ding's answer. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I sugguest you to use [Masonry](https://github.com/SnapKit/Masonry) ,when phone becomes landscape ,you can use `mas_updateConstraints` or `mas_remakeConstraints` to change it's constraint.